# Object not found! Error 404 page with slim

Tags: php, slim-3

I get

> Object not found! Error 404

When I say

```
$app->get('/signup', 'AuthController:getSignUp');
```

But It works when I run

```
$app->get('/', 'AuthController:getSignUp');
```

In my routes.php this is how I run it http://localhost/Authentication/public/index.php/signup and It show me the page

> Object not found! Error 404

here is my .htaccess

```
ewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
```

okay i get where i made the mistike i am supposed to run it like this
   http://localhost/Authentication/public/index.php/signup
not like this http://localhost/Authentication/public/signup, and it works like a charm. thanks everyone

Comment: We can't see your local host. Its local to your computer. 404 means the resource isn't found so make sure the path is where you think it is. Good luck!

Comment: Show us your .htaccess file.

Comment: @AdamA here this is my .htaccess  ewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]

Comment: Hi @Seid In both your comment reply to AdamA and in the post edit, your "RewriteEngine on" was misspelt, as ewriteEngine. Not sure if this was the issue or just a mis-paste. Please confirm if you managed to solve the issue and how.